# Flutter cannot build for iOS after Xcode upgrade

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I have an old project that didn't work on in the last 8 months and came back this week.
No code changes nothing, I just updated to Xcode `Version 12.4 (12D4e)` as my iPhone iOS is upgraded and could not run the app.

Now I'm facing lots of troubles, cannot build anymore for iOS

I got these errors

```
Building for iOS, but the linked and embedded framework 'Flutter. framework' was built for iOS + iOS Simulator.
```

I tried all sort of things without success like

1. flutter clean
2. rm -rf ios/Pods && cd ios/; pod install --repo-update
3. rm -rf ios/Flutter/App.framework

All the above together and nothing worked to get rid of the error.

My flutter version

```
Flutter 1.12.13+hotfix.8 • channel unknown • unknown source
Framework • revision 0b8abb4724 (1 year, 4 months ago) • 2020-02-11 11:44:36 -0800
Engine • revision e1e6ced81d
Tools • Dart 2.7.0
```

Flutter doctor is also happy

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel unknown, v1.12.13+hotfix.8, on macOS 11.4 20F71, locale en-DE)
 
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 12.4)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)
```

I knew my flutter version is old, so please don't suggest updating. Updating is very hard as I tried but I have to update all code and many libraries are not available in the new version.

So please flutter experts any idea how to solve this?

Update 1 June 2021:
I downgraded to old xcode version by downloading manually `Version 11.4 (11E146)`. I could build `archive` fine here the app, then trying to publish in app store I got this error:

```
SDK Version Issue. This app was built with the iOS 13.4 SDK. All iOS apps submitted to the App Store must be built with the iOS 14 SDK or later, included in Xcode 12 or later.
```

So I cannot downgrade, or use new one I got stuck in changing and deploying the ios version...

Comment: Are you confusing "update flutter to 2.x" with "update dart to behave NNBD instead of legacy"?  Because you can upgrade flutter without using NNBD, and all your chosen libs and code will just work.

Comment: Hi @RandalSchwartz. I am not interested in updating dart of flutter. As I described here, I updated xcode after 8 months  and cannot build anymore for ios simulator or device

Answer (score 1):

Try following

```
flutter clean
rm -Rf ios/Pods
rm -Rf ios/.symlinks
rm -Rf ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework
rm -Rf ios/Flutter/Flutter.podspec
```

Comment: Thanks. Tried that now, still same error "    error: Building for iOS Simulator, but the linked and embedded framework 'Flutter.framework' was built for iOS + iOS Simulator. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
"